# Can I access my currently Delegated Tezos from my Nano Ledger as I cannot access or restore my Tezbox

Tags: ledger, tezbox

I currently have a very concerning issue. I have some Tezos linked to a Nano ledger which I have delegated using the Tezbox web  wallet. However for some reason  the password is not working (although it is the correct one)and I cannot locate the mnemonic passphrase to restore the wallet.
When I log into my Nano ledger I can see the Tezos but cannot send them to my Kraken account in order to move them off the tezbox.
So, 
1) Are the Tezos gone, if I cannot access the Tezbox or restore it.
2) I was hoping I could somehow access them via the nano ledger, I think that is where the private keys are stored.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify if you lost your ledger mnemonic or the tezbox mnemonic ? Note that tezbox support is available here https://t.me/TezTechLabs